# Rails: Create a new record with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

When the user clicks the link "New Week", a new record of the model week should be created and appended to the end of the list.

Here is my view `weeks/index.html.erb`

```
<h1> Weeks </h1>
<%= link_to "New Week", action: :create,  method:"post" %>

<% @weeks.each do |week| %>
<ul>
  <li> <%= link_to week.id, week %> </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I am also not quite sure what to put in the create action for the weeks controller. This is what I have so far. The view above is routed to be the root.

```
  def create
    @week = Week.create(params[:week])
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

When I click the link, it submits a POST action, but nothing else happens. A new record is not created. My debug(params) look like this.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
method: post
action: index
controller: weeks
```

**Update**

I got it to work by doing

`<%= link_to "New Week", { action: :create, :id => Week.new },  method:"post" %>`

but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it. Can anyone with expertise expand upon what is happening here?

Comment: You're not passing any params through the `link_to`, which is why its not creating anything

Comment: Okay I am passing the id like so `<%= link_to "New Week", { action: :create, :week => week.id },  method:"post" %> ` and I am getting an error: `undefined local variable or method 'week'`